# Replication issue on all 3 domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, replication

We have 3 domain controllers in server 2012. Replication is failing miserably.

Repadmin /replsummary

dc1 rpc server not available

dc 2 rpc server not available

dc 3 "Insufficient attributes were given to create an object"

I wll be coming with dcdiag output soon.

But one thing still stuck in my mind is that during dcdiag outputs were this dc is not advertising as time servr when the time configuration is correct on pdc and dc's

Replsummary and Dcdiag
C:\Users\admin>

```
repadmin /replsummary
Replication Summary Start Time: 2016-01-13 09:58:55

Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  ......


Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
DC01                  26m:42s    0 /  10    0
DDC                   26m:47s    0 /  10    0
 DC02          03h:58m:50s   10 /  10  100  (1722) The RPC server is una
vailable.
```

C:\Users\admin>

```
repadmin /replsummary
Replication Summary Start Time: 2016-01-13 09:58:55

Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  ......


Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC01                  26m:42s    0 /  10    0
 DDC                   26m:47s    0 /  10    0
 DC02          03h:58m:50s   10 /  10  100  (1722) The RPC server is una
vailable.





C:\Users\admin>dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DC02
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: -Irving\DC02
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... DC02 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Irving\DC02
      Starting test: Advertising
         Warning: DC02 is not advertising as a time server.
         ......................... DC02 failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... DC02 passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
         ......................... DC02 passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... DC02 passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... DC02 passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... DC02 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... DC02 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... DC02 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         [DC02] User credentials does not have permission to perform
         this operation.
         The account used for this test must have network logon privileges
         for this machine's domain.
         ......................... DC02 failed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... DC02 passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         [Replications Check,DC02] DsReplicaGetInfo(PENDING_OPS, NULL)
         failed, error 0x2105 "Replication access was denied."
         ......................... DC02 failed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... DC02 passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
            Could not open NTDS Service on DC02, error 0x5
            "Access is denied."
         ......................... DC02 failed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         ......................... DC02 passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... DC02 passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : ssd
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ssd passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ssd passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : ssd.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... ssd.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... ssd.local passed test Intersite
```

Comment: has this been working and broke recently? looking at your replsummary there were only 10 fails, meaning it's working not too long before you ran repadmin. If you didn't make any changes on DCs, and have done health checks other than replication, then the only thing left is network. Make sure you have connectivity among DCs. portqryUI pre-defined domain test is a good tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First 2 DC seems to be a network issue, are you able to connect the DC
Check the role server (PDC) first and resolve the issue then check other 2 DC's to fix the replication issues

If DC's are not replicated more then tombstone time period the need a rebuild to resolve the issue

Comment: There seems to be issue with lingering objects.

 strange problem occurred with one of the users desktop, if he paste files from local users to his domain account desktop at the time of logoff all files goes missing

Comment: @jacksh Unless your DC has been offline for a very long time (>tombstone time), or you manually change time, you shouldn't have lingering objects. It will also give you very specific error messages. I'd rule that out.

Comment: the issue has been resolved found multiple network adapters configured with ip address on one of the dc

Comment: To help others- strange problem occurred with one of the users desktop, if he paste files from local users to his domain account desktop at the time of logoff all files goes missing.

has been fixed by removing the users from the members of domain guests.